# Tweepy find spaces by user ID

Tags: python, tweepy

Is there a way to search for a spaces by user id?
I tried different values in the query but it didn't work.

```
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN, 
                         consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY, 
                         consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                         access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, 
                         access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

space_url = client.get_space( id="ID_NUMBER")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the [get_spaces](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_spaces) method.

```py
spaces = client.get_spaces(user_ids="ID_NUMBER")
```

Comment: Excellent.
But it only finds the host for me.
Is it possible to search for a speaker?
When I search for a speaker, it returns me no rooms.

Response(data=None, includes={}, errors=[], meta={'result_count': 0})

Comment: @Sasiadstar You should read the the description of all the methods to be sure, but I don't think that this is possible with the twitter API.